# Add Geotags to photos from GPX track

Tags: metadata, exiftool, gps

What's the best way to add geotags to photos if I have a GPX file with my location track?

I don't have lightroom and I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Seems like exiftool is a surefire way to do it. Any that work directly with Apple Photos and don't require command line?

Comment: See also: [Is there a GUI application to quickly geotag photos / run exiftool with multiple parameters?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/40182)

Comment: While the question and title are specific to raw files, the answers apply to JPEG files as well: [Is there software on Macintosh for adding GPS data to RAW files?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/56301)

Answer (score 0):

Use [GeoTag](https://www.snafu.org/GeoTag/)

It reads your DPX files and uses ExifTool under the hood to manipulate the EXIF data in your pics.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [HoudahGeo.](https://www.houdah.com/houdahGeo/?lang=en) I am not associated with the product, just a happy user. This is a Mac app, and really does excel at geotagging photos. It allows easy bulk tagging, and includes some extremely useful features, such as adjusting time, time zones, and provides a map for more precise pinpointing locations.